# PowerShell remove dot in regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following one-liner in powershell:

```
cat raw.txt | select-string -Pattern "\A[s]\w{1,12}\.\b" -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

**Returns:**

```
saltri.
swoptimusprime.
swdecepticons.
```

The **question** is **how to remove the dots "." from my lines of hostnames**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you're looking for something more sophisticated than tacking a `.Replace('.','')` on the end of `$_.Value`?

Comment: i have that function in place :

function remDots
{
 # remove dots 
 $get_raw = Get-Content $output_file_raw
 $get_raw -replace '[.]','' > c:\ps\hosts.txt
}

Comment: @JamesQMurphy but yes responding to your question the direct response would be something in the regex that would do that instead of replace

Comment: `\.\b` -> `(?=\.\b)`

Comment: @PetSerAl that worked thanks, can you explain what i was doing wrong if you can of course.

Comment: @drd0sPy `(?=pattern)` is positive look ahead group which check following text to match the pattern, but does not capture it as part of match.

Comment: @PetSerAl: *but does not capture it as part of match.* => *but is not included into the returned match value*. Just to avoid the notion of capturing that is a bit different thing in regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It does make sense to call this _capturing_ and even the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) use this terminology, calling lookahead assertions _noncapturing_. Both `Select-String` and `-match` always capture the _overall_ match, even in the absence of _explicit_ capture groups (think of the overall match as an _implicit_ capture group).

Comment: I would disagree with that terminological approach because one can *capture* subtexts with capture groups inside positive lookbehinds and lookaheads. `-match` can both match and capture. Generally speaking, there is an ambiguity between what a *capture* term may mean.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks for pointing out the somewhat counter-intuitive fact that capture groups can also be used inside positive lookbehind/lookahead assertions.
However, I don't see ambiguity in the term _capture_; I just see _levels_ (nesting) of capturing: in the context of the overall regex, lookaround assertions are _noncapturing_, irrespective of whether they happen to contain (by definition always) _capturing_ capture groups.
`-match` (in addition to matching) _always captures_, as reflected in `$matches[0]`, whether capture groups are present or not.

Comment: @mklement0: so, you are using the term "capture" as "put the text matched into a match object", while I prefer to narrow it down to "take a part of the matched string (lookbarounds still match text) matching specific subpattern inside a pair of unescaped parentheses and put it into a capture group memory buffer with a corresponding ID."

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Understood, but your personal preference is inconsistent with the official docs (see link) and, I think, with common usage: I don't think that preference will serve you well. The word _capture_ in _capture group_ (which is not an official term in most documentation, btw) is not the word to focus on, because it shares the  default capturing behavior with the overall match; it's the _group_ part, or, more accurately, the _subexpression_ part - and, as is reflected in the _expression_ / _sub_-expression correspondence, they are considered _nested_ versions of _the same thing_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), in a comment on the question, provided the crucial pointer: **use a [positive lookahead assertion (`(?=...)`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) to match an additional part of the input, without including that part in the captured match**.

If we apply this to your solution and simplify it, we get:

```
Get-Content raw.txt | % { if ($_ -match '^s\w{1,12}(?=\.\b)') { $matches[0] } }
```

The sub-expression `\.\b` - a literal `.` followed by a (non-capturing) transition to a word character, `\b` - is *matched*, but not *captured*; that is, `$matches[0]`, the element of the special `$matches` variable that contains the matched part of the string, does *not* include the `.`

However, since we're using `-match` and accessing the special `$matches` variable afterward, we may simplify matters with a capture group (`(...)`) in the regex, whose captured substring we can access by index `1`, since it is the *first* (and only) capture group in the regex:

```
Get-Content raw.txt | % { if ($_ -match '^(s\w{1,12})\.\b') { $matches[1] } }
```

---

**Notes on your solution attempt** (aside from including the `.` in the match):

- You're using `Get-Content` without switch `-Raw`, which means that the input lines are sent *individually* through the pipeline:

  - Therefore, there's no reason to use `\A` instead of the more familiar start-of-string/line anchor `^`, because these two only differ with *multi-line* input.
  - Because you're anchoring the match at the start of the line, the `-AllMatches` option is pointless, because by definition there can be at most *1* match per line.
- As you can see, a single `%` (`ForEach-Object`) block with `-match` is sufficient in this case and simplifies matters; it both returns less information not needed in this case and performs better than `Select-String`.

Answer (score 0):

As I dont know how your Text looks like, grouping the hostname should be sufficent (shorter attempt via `-match`):

```
cat raw.txt | % {$_ -match "\A([s]\w{1,12})\.\b"; $matches[1] }
```

Comment: Well the text if you do a direct cat to the raw.txt is exactly like you see on the question pretty much @restless1987.

always a string that ends with a dot like for example:

server1.
server2.